# How to display custom format text into select options tags?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to display following text inside the dropdown options.

```
1 day  - until Friday 18th Dec      1     10.50
2 days - until Saturday 19th Dec    2     20.50
continue ....
```

It is not working, It will remove the space and display in unlike format.

```
1 day - until Friday 18th Dec 1 10.50
2 days - until Saturday 19th Dec 2 20.50
```

I have also tried with < pre >...< /pre > tag but it is still not working

Note : My select dropdown content is coming from C# code.

Comment: You can create custom drop down like this http://jsfiddle.net/K66nN/

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&nbsp;` for space between your text. 
Eg:   `&nbsp;&nbsp;` means two spaces.

Comment: Than you can add `\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0` in string for spaces, add it in c# code when you are creating that string

Comment: Why don't you create custom dropdown like this http://jsfiddle.net/K66nN/